# What is the word for the state of being a boss?

Tags: single-word-requests

When people are members of a group it's called [having] membership.

Is there a similar word for people who are bosses of a group, like "bossship"? :)

I found the word "directorate" but it means a group of people ("the board of directors of a company"), not the fact that this person is a boss of some group.

Comment: It's a bit of an oxymoron, but you can say they're a member of "management".  A person directly in charge of peons is a "first-line manager".

Comment: How about [*bossdom*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bossdom)?

Comment: Directors are given a *directorship*. Beyond that your second paragraph says you want a word for "the bosses of a group" but your third that you do not want a terms for the group who are the bosses of an organization.  This is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Leader* is a generic term for a person in charge of *members*.

We might say that *member* is to *membership* as *leader* is to *leadership*.

> **Leadership**
>   : a position as a leader of a group, organization, etc. - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leadership)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be a little facetious, you might try [*reign*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reign).

> reign
>
> ```
> noun
> 1.
> the period during which a sovereign occupies the throne.
> 2.
> royal rule or authority; sovereignty.
> 3.
> dominating power or influence:
> ```